# How to remove object in object array : jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i'm confused i was trying to remove object in object array using `jquery` here is my code , [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/Zg7qA/)

```
var x = new Array() ; 
var y = {} ; 
y.name = 'myName' ; 
y.age = 28 ; 
y.phone = 27895556 ; 
y.info = [{name:'x' ,age:58} ,{name:'y' , age:15}]
x.push(y) ;

 $.each(x , function(index,value) {
        $.each(value.info , function(i,v){
            if(v.name == 'x'){
            this.splice(i,1) ; 
         }

      });
  });
```

i was trying to tell the `if` condition to remove the object with `v.name` = 'x' ​but i get this `error` *Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'splice'*

**UPDATE** i need to have something like :  `y.info = [{name:'x' ,age:58} ,{name:'y' , age:15}]` after `splice()`

any idea what i'm doing wrong **Thanks**

Comment: Change it to `x.splice` - `this` is the array element.

Comment: are you just trying to remove that object from `y.info`, i.e. leaving `{name: y, age: 15 }`, or do want to remove the entire object `y` from the array `x` ?

Comment: no just leaving `{name: y, age: 15 }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just trying to remove the inner array element that contains the value `{name: 'x'}` then the array you want to `splice` is the `value.info` of the outer loop:

```
$.each(x, function(index, value) {
    $.each(value.info, function(i, v) {
        if (v.name === 'x') {
            value.info.splice(i, 1) ; 
        }
    });
});
```

However this code suffers from the problem that you shouldn't modify an array's length while iterating over it with `$.each`.  This alternate code fixes that problem:

```
$.each(x, function(index, value) {
    var info = value.info;
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; ) {
        if (info[i].name === 'x') {
            info.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried your answer and it give me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` don't know why [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/Zg7qA/3/)

Comment: @MinaGabriel because after splicing the array in next iteration there is no object or name property at that index.

Comment: i don't understand ? we removed `{name:'x' ,age:58}` from `x.info` i should now have `y.info = [{name:'y' , age:15}]` i don't even have `array x`

Comment: @MinaGabriel you _do_ have an array `x`.  However this code still doesn't work because it modifies the array while it's being iterated over.